# Is this a convergent sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> $s_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[4]{n}}$

I'm using the ration test so I rewrote it like so:

$\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}} \cdot \frac{n^{\frac{1}{4}}}{(-1)^n} =\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{-n}{n+1}=-1$

But wolfram shows that my limit should be $0$.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: (if you meant the series $\sum_n s_n$) it is an alternating series, and the ratio test gives $1$ yes, so it is useless. note that as any alternativing series, by grouping the terms by two, it becomes absolutely convergent : $\sum_n  (2n-1)^{-1/4}- (2n)^{-1/4}$ with $(2n-1)^{-1/4}- (2n)^{-1/4} < C n^{-5/4}$ for some $C$

Comment: Is your $s_n$ a sequence or a series? ratio test is for series, and the sum of your $s_n$ doesn't give an answer from ratio test. But if it is just a sequence then $s_n$ goes to zero.

Comment: Why negative n and why aren't they to the 1/4 powerm  Oh, well, it doesn't matter.  The limit is 1 so the ratio test fails and you don't know if the series converges or diverges.  You have to try something else.

Comment: Don't use Ratio Test, which is really designed to test the convergence of **series**. You seem to have a sequence. As $n$ big, $\sqrt[4]{n}$ gets big, while $(-1)^n$ stays small in absolute value, so $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[4]{n}}$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean sequence here. Remember there is a theorem that says if $|s_{n}|\rightarrow 0$, then $s_{n}\rightarrow 0$. Now we can see that $\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}\rightarrow 0$, so our series converges to $0$.

If you meant the series $\sum{s_{n}}$ then you could use the Leibniz Test. $\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}\geq0$ $\forall n$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}=0$, and $\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}$ is decreasing $\forall n$. So we know that our series converges.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test isn't for sequences like $\{s_n\} $; it is for series like $\sum s_n $. $s_n \rightarrow 0$ should be obvious but it isn't obvious that $\sum s_n $ converges.

So we do the ratio test.  $\lim |s_{n+1}/s_n|=\lim |n^{1/4}/(n+1)^{1/4}|=1$.  If the limit were less than 1, then we know $\sum s_n$ converges.  If the limit is more than one, then we know $\sum s_n$ diverges.  But if the limit equals 1, as it does in this case, we don't know a f@#%ing thing.

So the ratio test doesn't tell us anything.

On the other hand we didn't need to do the ratio test at all.  $|s_{n+1}| < |s_n|$ and the signs alternate and $s_n \rightarrow 0$.  So $\sum s_n$  is an alternating decreasing series so it converges.

To what, is another question altogether, but certainly not 0.